# Which UI Control should I use that has three states?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibutton

I want to use a button which has three states:

1. `Not selected`: Nothing from sub-categories are selected
2. `Selected`: All sub-categories are selected
3. `Grayed`: Some sub-categories are selected

I tried using `UIButton` and used three images for Normal, Selected and Highlighted states. But Tapping button would cause changing the states from Normal to Highlighted then to Selected, and all images would be shown for a fraction of second, and it was annoying. So I used three images for Normal, Selected and Disabled states. Everything works fine except that when button goes to Disabled state, no tap event on disabled `UIButton` is triggered, and the user can't change the state of `UIButton` when it goes to disabled state.

Any suggestion how can I achieve three completely working state with `UIButton`, or using any other UI Control?

Comment: @meggar I want all three states on one place, like CheckBox.

Comment: You might want to subclass UIButton

Comment: @meggar Any suggestion how can I add another state to UIButton subclass?

Comment: You might want to subclass UIControl! In fact, you could even write a thing that looks and behaves just like a checkbox, which is just what you want anyway.

Comment: @Hadu do you need to use the states? why not store your own state variable and update the images programatically

Comment: @meggar Thanks for the tip, I added some variables as States and used them instead of UIButton standard states. Now everything is they way it should be!